# Java - How to stop or continue DO WHILE loop if it cannot read the boolean values

Tags: java, boolean

What I am trying to achieve is: the user should input a String of dates. I will then take each date and validate it and add it to an ArrayList. 
If the date does not match the regular expression it should restart the do while loop and ask for input again.

I am validating several inputs in a method, and with all of them I use a boolean value "inputNotApproved" to tell if the do while should end or not. It has worked fine with more simple validations, such as name e.g., but because I have to run an extra while loop inside the do while loop, the program cannot read the boolean value "inputNotApproved".

How can I tell the do while loop to restart, in case some of the dates does not match the regex.

```
do {
ArrayList<String> inputDatesList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
System.out.print("Available booking dates (DD-MM-YYYY DD-MM-YYYY ...): ");

       while(input.hasNext()){
            String date = input.next();

            if(date.matches("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-((20)(17|18))")){
                inputDatesList.add(date);
                inputNotApproved = false;
            }
            else{
                inputNotApproved = true;
                System.out.println("The date format is not correct (DD-MM-YYYY).");
            }
        }
}
while(inputNotApproved);
```

An example of where I used it and the inputNotApproved worked as intended:

```
do {
            System.out.print("Email address: ");
            String inputEmail = input.nextLine();

            if(inputEmail.matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")){
                inputNotApproved = false;
                newDentist.setEmail(inputEmail);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ERROR! The email is not in the correct format.");
                inputNotApproved = true;
                }
}

    while(inputNotApproved);
```

Any help is much appreciated. How can I make the loop listen to the true/false of "inputNotApproved". Thank you.

I also tried the following, where it reacted to making the boolean false, but the do-while does not continue.

```
do {
            ArrayList<String> inputDatesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.print("Available booking dates (DD-MM-YYYY): ");
            inputNotApproved = true;

            while(input.hasNext() && input.hasNext("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-((20)(17|18))")){
                String date = input.next();
                inputDatesList.add(date);
                inputNotApproved = false;
            }


            if (!input.hasNext("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-((20)(17|18))")){
                System.out.println("The date format is not correct (DD-MM-YYYY).");
                continue;
            }
while(inputNotApproved);
```

---

LATEST UPDATE.

I added a break and !inputNotApproved in the inner while loop. But now I notice that the loop doesn't end when the date input are correct and matches the regex. It just keeps taking input.

My code now looks like this:

```
do {
            ArrayList<String> inputDatesList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Temporary ArrayList, will be sent to ArrayList in Dentist class
            System.out.print("Available booking dates (DD-MM-YYYY): ");

        while(input.hasNext() && !inputNotApproved){
            String date = input.next();

            if(date.matches("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-((20)(17|18))")){
                inputDatesList.add(date);
                inputNotApproved = false;
            }
            else{
                inputNotApproved = true;
                System.out.println("The date format is not correct (DD-MM-YYYY).");
                break;
            }
        }
}
    while(inputNotApproved);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the program cannot read the boolean value"? What error are you seeing? This comes down to the scope of the variable, if it's declared before the `do` in your example, what you have here should work.

Comment: I don't get an error, the do-while loop just doesn't start over if a wrong date is entered, I want the system to ask for input again (the do-while starting again). The boolean value "inputNotApproved" is declared before the do-while loop.

Comment: In the second section of code it works. But the first section which check the dates it doesn't seem to react to what inputNotApproved is set to during the loop.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with what the intent of this is, but as a general pointer for something that might help you see what's going on, if you're using an IDE (like Eclipse, IntelliJ or NetBeans), look into how to set a breakpoint so you can step through the code line by line and see what's happening. If you're not using an IDE, you can achieve much the same effect by adding a whole load of temporary `System.out.println` statements to see which bits of code are executing when, and what the values of the variables are at each point.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your exact requirements - for example, if a date is invalid, do you want the user to re-enter all the dates, or just the one that's invalid?

As a starter, that I think meets your requirements, you could just add an additional condition to your inner while loop, to make it something like:

```
while (input.hasNext() && !inputNotApproved)
```

That logic feels a bit messy, so you might be better off extracting the inner while loop into a separate method, which could return the list of dates, if they are all correctly formatted and throw an exception if something is incorrectly formatted. In your `do...while` loop then you just catch the exception, and set your variable to trigger it to ask for the input again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I added the !inputNotApproved to the inner while loop. But now I notice that the do-while does not seem to end when the dates are correct. It just continues to take input

Answer (score 1):

If I had some more reputation, I would have commented that you are initializing your ArrayList inside of your loop, which means it is a local variable. Every time your program goes over the loop, it recreates your ArrayList meaning your method is doing nothing! I suggest initializing it outside the loop so it can actually be useful.

Another thing, you only change the value of inputNotApproved within the while loop. Are you sure that your program always enters it? If not, you should set it to true out outside of the inner while loop as you did in your working example.

You are setting the inputNotApproved within the while loop, but it only restarts the outer do loop when your program is done with this while loop! You can use a break statement after the inputNotApproved=true to exit out of the while loop and restart the do loop. Another alternative is to add a check in your while loop like so:

```
while(input.hasNext() && !inputNotApproved)
```

I put this code into my debugger and it seems fine. I don't your program shouldn't be looping when the input is correct. It does, however, continue looping when your program sees a wrong input because in the version you posted, you don't ask for input.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner("12-12-2017 11-04-2017 12-12-2017 11-04-2017 12-12-2017 11-04-2017");
      Boolean inputNotApproved = false;
      do {
            ArrayList<String> inputDatesList = new ArrayList<String>(); // Temporary ArrayList, will be sent to ArrayList in Dentist class
            System.out.print("Available booking dates (DD-MM-YYYY): ");

        while(input.hasNext() && !inputNotApproved){
             String date = input.next();

            if(date.matches("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-((20)(17|18))")){
                inputDatesList.add(date);
                inputNotApproved = false;
                System.out.println(date);
            }
            else{
                inputNotApproved = true;
                System.out.println("The date format is not correct (DD-MM-YYYY).");
                break;
            }
        }
      }
      while(inputNotApproved);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, the ArrayList is only temporary for validating purposes. I didn't include it in this example to make the code more simple, but by the end of the do-while I add the "temporary" ArrayList to a permanent ArrayList in another class. :)

Comment: Ok good. Next time try not to add the initialization, because then I would have assumed you initialized the Array List outside of the code you were posting.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, changing your else to include a break would probably fix it, to get out of the inner loop, and triggering the second while condition.

```
        else{
                inputNotApproved = true;
                System.out.println("The date format is not correct (DD-MM-YYYY).");
                break;
            }
```

**EDIT:**
You could try something like this, if you want it simpler.

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        List<String> inputDatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Available booking dates (DD-MM-YYYY): ");
        while(!in.lines().allMatch(input -> input.matches("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-((20)(17|18))"))){
            System.out.println("The date format is not correct (DD-MM-YYYY).");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }
        inputDatesList.addAll(in.lines().collect(toList()));
```

Comment: THANK YOU! The break did it!... wow, so simple and I been struggling for hours.

Comment: A `break` is fine if this is just some small throw-away project, but if it's likely to grow, be aware that it's easy to get confusing and hard to see what's going on if you control the flow of the application like this.

Comment: Now I notice that the do-while does not seem to end when the dates are correct. It just continues to take input.